# async calls at the same time causing error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

I have a function which is an async call that sends emails, what happens is if the function gets called at the same time I get the error:

> The control is currently busy

How can I not get this error and for that second call to work? Will a delay work?

```
public static void MyEatTaskAsync(DataRowCollection rows)
{
    MyTaskWorkerDelegate worker = new MyTaskWorkerDelegate(EmailAutomationTask.setEmailAndSend);
    AsyncCallback completedCallback = new AsyncCallback(AsyncMethods.MyTaskCompletedCallback);

    lock (AsyncMethods._sync)
    {
        if (AsyncMethods._myTaskIsRunning)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The control is currently busy.");

        worker.BeginInvoke(rows, completedCallback, null);
        AsyncMethods._myTaskIsRunning = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a lock here?

Comment: The posted method has too many black box. It's hard to exmaine if there's anything wrong with ur threading model. But, sounds like the error you get is pretty straightforward tho. Looks like your email control is a singleton resources that doesn't support multi-threaded loading ? I would implement a queue buffer for the email task so that your async process can fire-and-forget. And having another thread picking up the email task one by one. Hope that help.

Comment: I have code that gets some rows and then calls that method, do you have an example of what you mean? sorry i dont understand.                                                                                                                                                                                              DataRowCollection rows = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows;

AsyncMethods.MyEatTaskAsync(rows);

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you need to do some some task ("completedCallback") after completion of sending a batch of emails (content of rows).
Caller of "MyEatTaskAsync" can call this method again while it is still processing, that is why you have to implement a lock here.
Easy way of doing this is implement an "await" in the caller till the "MyEatTaskAsync" is completed.

Read this article and understand how it works.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx